# Cuda and Thread Concurrancy

Tags: cuda

So I'm taking an algorithms class, and for my final project I'm decided to take some of the Cuda stuff I learned at work and put together some GPGPU sorting algorithms an evaluate their growth over different objects. But then I've gone and confused myself over how many threads actually are running at the same time...Please let me know if I am understanding this incorectly.

So I have a GeForce GT 650M. Cuda Capable 3.0 card.

It has 2 multiprocessors, so each processor takes 1 block at once. That part I get...but beyond that is where it starts to get fuzzy for me.

The largest number of threads running concurrent is 384: 2 MPU*192 Cores/MPU, or 2 MPUs*6 Warps/MPU*

Each MPU has a set of 192 Cuda Cores, which means that each processor can do up to 192 operations at once (yes? no?) regardless of the maintained thread count. So the parellization factor <=384, correct?

Each block is running n<=1024 threads at once, which the warp scheduler will choose which ones are taking up the 192 cores. A warp (of 32 threads, I believe, but I could be wrong) is the group of concurrency that is set.

When a kernel is called, the GPU distributes the blocks equally. If you have a odd number of blocks, there will be a period of time where you have 192 threads.

However, if a single thread in a warp finishes early, then it must wait until all other threads in the warp finish before it skips on to the next warp.

A block of warps will finish before moving to the next block. Up to 16 blocks are allowed to run at the same time on a MPU. (why on earth would this happen, btw?). However, all blocks must finish before calling the next kernel.

Is this right?

Comment: Surely you can construct a more useful question than "here is a lomg list of mostly wrong/mostly irrelevent things I think I know about the CUDA hardware execution model, are they right?"

Answer (score 2):

It's preferred that you ask one question per question.  Furthermore, there are many questions like this on SO.  You might try searching and reading some of those.

> each processor takes 1 block at once.

That could be true for a specific code, but it is not generally true.  An SM (MPU) can have multiple threadblocks "open", and on a cycle-by-cycle basis, selecting warps from any of them to schedule for execution.

> each processor can do up to 192 operations at once

It depends on the operation.  Single precision floating point add/multiply operations, probably yes.  Others, [probably not](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions).

> regardless of the maintained thread count

What?  No.  If you're not running a full complement of threads, and in fact usually if you are not oversubscribed on threads (i.e. warps) the machine will not likely run at full capacity.

> So the parellization factor <=384, correct?

Do you want to define parallelization factor, it's not entirely obvious?  We've already established that for some types of operations, you could get for example 384 SP floating point operations retired in a single clock cycle.  But your mileage may vary, depending on the operation. (Integer ops will typically be less.)

> (why on earth would this happen, btw?).

Because, in fact we generally want to oversubscribe the SM's.  If an SM has 192 cuda "cores", that does not mean we want to think about exactly 192 threads (or 6 warps) for that SM.  This is a common misconception in GPU programming.  A GPU hides latency by doing rapid context switching from a warp that is stalled (perhaps due to a memory reference) to a warp that is not stalled.  If there are no other (un-stalled) warps available, then the SM will stall waiting for a warp to become ready to execute, and your performance will suffer.  Having lots of "extra" warps ready to go helps prevent a SM stall.

> Is this right?

Some of your assertions are correct.  I've tried to address the ones that seemed incorrect, but it seems overall your understanding is not clear (as you say, "fuzzy").  In my opinion, your question is poorly written.  It's nice to have one or a very small number of "crisp" questions to answer. This question feels like you want a dialog or a treatise, and SO is not designed for that.  If you want a comprehensive intro to CUDA, read the available [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html) or take some of the available [webinars](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-computing-webinars).